# Comparing same columns in the same table

Tags: sql

If I have a data like this in table1

```
column1 column2 date
111     00      2016-10-11
111     00      2016-10-11
111     20      2016-10-12
111     20      2016-10-12
222     00      2016-10-11
222     20      2016-10-12
333     20      2016-10-11
333     20      2016-10-12
```

I want to build a query which picks out only 333 as duplicate because 
column1 = column1 (333=333), column2 = column2 (20 = 20) and date <> date (2016-10-11 <> 2016-10-12
Thank you

Comment: which RDBMS, sql-server, Orcale, mysql...etc?

Comment: Could you please edit your request? Your request isn't clear enough to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems a self join would work...

```
SELECT T1.*, T2.*
FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN table2 T2
 on T1.Column1 = T2.Column1
and T2.column2 = T2.Column2
and T1.Date <> T2.Date
```

or an exists (faster but access to only T1 data)

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM Table1 T1
WHERE Exists (Select 1 
              from table1 T2 
              where T1.Column1 = T2.Column1
                and T2.column2 = T2.Column2
                and T1.Date <> T2.Date)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select column1 from table1 t
join table1 jt
  on t.column1 = jt.column1
  and t.column2 = jt.column2
  and jt.date <> jt.date
```

Answer (score 1):

use a self join

```
 select t1.column1
 from my_table t1
 inner join my_table t2
 on t1.column1 = t2.column2
 and t1.ccolumn2 = t2.column2
 and t1.date <> t2.date
```